# Difficulties in merging two array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have two arrays, I want to merge these two arrays into single array. Please view the detail below:

First Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 7
            [b] => 8
            [c] => 9
        )
)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [d] => 100

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [d] => 200

        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [d] => 300

        )
)
```

I want this result. Does somebody know how to do this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
            [d] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 6
            [d] => 200
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 7
            [b] => 8
            [c] => 9
            [d] => 300
        )

    )
```

Hope you have understand the question. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: When i use array_merge_recursive(), i get this result:

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 2
            [c] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 5
            [c] => 6
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 7
            [b] => 8
            [c] => 9
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [d] => 100

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [d] => 200

        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [d] => 300

        )
)
```

Help!

Comment: `array_merge_recursive()`

Comment: link to docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: @Peppegiuseppe Please use `var_export` to show us your Arrays so we do not have to manually retype them as it will make testing easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Loop through secondary array
- Check to see if the secondary key exists in the primary array

  - If it does, merge them.

#### The code

```
foreach($arr2 as $intKey => $arrElement) {
    if(array_key_exists($intKey, $arr1)) {
        $arr1[$intKey] = array_merge($arr1[$intKey], $arrElement);
    }
}
```

#### For example;

```
<?php

$arr1 = array( 0 => array("a" => 1,
                          "b" => 2,
                          "c" => 3
                         ),
                1 => array("a" => 1,
                        "b" => 2,
                        "c" => 3
                ),
                2 => array("a" => 1,
                        "b" => 2,
                        "c" => 3
                ),
    );

$arr2 = array( 0 => array("d" => 4
                         ),
                1 => array("d" => 4
                ),
                2 => array("d" => 4
                ),
    );


foreach($arr2 as $intKey => $arrElement) {
    if(array_key_exists($intKey, $arr1)) {
        $arr1[$intKey] = array_merge($arr1[$intKey], $arrElement);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $arr1 );
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
> Array (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [a] => 1
>             [b] => 2
>             [c] => 3
>             [d] => 4
>         )
> 
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [a] => 1
>             [b] => 2
>             [c] => 3
>             [d] => 4
>         )
> 
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [a] => 1
>             [b] => 2
>             [c] => 3
>             [d] => 4
>         )
> 
> )
```

Answer (score 3):

Use recursive merge:

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, i've just tried it before.. see my edited question!